# free Ad serving solution for smaller php websites

Tags: php, advertising, looking-for-a-script, mysql

I'm looking for a very simple ad serving solution on my website, that can be hosted on my website. I have used openX and found it a bit complex for my needs. basically I need;

1. A way for advertisers to simply post their ad and pay using common payment methods visa/paypal etc
2. An interface for advertisers to track campaigns.

I used traffic spaces one and liked the idea, although i wanted to host the server myself. Performance issues.

Comment: You could join one of the many existing advertising solutions like google's or AdMedia. This way you don't have to worry setting up all by yourself.

Comment: My website is located in africa and many adserving solutions bring irrelevant adverts

Comment: How set are you on "free"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming from Africa your biggest issue will be getting a payment provider to let you sign up.

As for tools I believe the easiest are things like AdSense, Adbrite, things of that nature (Adbrite lets you put your own ads in, so they wouldn't be irrelevant).

Tools you customise yourself are going to be very heavy handed as it is a big problem to solve.